# Open several files in a specifc layout with a shortcut

Tags: window-splitting, bookmarks, keyboard-layout

I would like to open in emacs, with a shortcut/bookmark three files in this configuration:

```
_____________
|       | B |
|   A   |___|
|       | C |
|_______|___|
```

A is my main editing file, B is for the outline of what I write in A and C is for notes. Note that I manually set this layout because the second column is much smaller than what C-x 3 produces.

I'm using lawlist-bookmark -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284395/2112489 -- which allows me to use F5 and then a letter shortcut to open quickly a file configured. But with this solution, the opened file take all the space and I have to set manually the layout of emacs to achieve the picture above. I am looking for a solution which will open the three files in the specific geometry layout with one keystroke (after typing F5 to enter inside bookmarks "menu").

Is it possible?

My current bookmarks:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'lawlist-bookmark)
(defun lawlist-bookmark (choice)
  "Choices for directories and files."
  (interactive "cf[o]lder | [F]ile | ... )
  (cond
   ((eq choice ?o)
    (dired "~/folder"))
   ((eq choice ?f)
    (find-file "/~file.tex")
    (message "Opened:  %s" (buffer-name)))
 ....
   (t (message "Quit"))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be necessary to decide ahead of time what windows/buffers will be A, B and C.  The alist argument for the left `window-width` can be adjusted to taste -- it is presently hard-coded to 70.  This example uses an internal function `window--display-buffer`, which requires some general understanding of certain functions inside `window.el`.  The `selected-window` is letter `B`, but this can be changed (with a little coding) if so desired.

```lisp
(defun example-fn ()
  "To try this example, type:  M-x example-fn"
  (interactive)
  (let ((a (dired-noselect "~"))
        (b (find-file-noselect "~/foo.txt"))
        (c (get-buffer-create "*scratch*")))
    (delete-other-windows)
    (switch-to-buffer b)
    ;; See the doc-strings for `split-window' and `window--display-buffer'.
    (window--display-buffer
     a (split-window (selected-window) nil 'left)
     'window '((window-width . 70)) display-buffer-mark-dedicated)
    (window--display-buffer
     c (split-window (selected-window) nil 'below)
     'window nil display-buffer-mark-dedicated)))
```

And, if a keyboard shortcut is desired, it can be set with:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'example-fn)
```

---

To incorporate this new example into `lawlist-bookmark`, the entire `let` section of `example-fn` can be added or just use the name of the function itself.

```lisp
(defun lawlist-bookmark (choice)
  "Choices for directories and files.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284395/2112489"
  (interactive "c[3]-way | [D]ired | [v]ocab.org | [g]td.org | [d]iary.org | [n]otes.org")
  (cond
    ((eq choice ?3)
     (example-fn))
    ((eq choice ?D)
     (dired "/very/long/and/boring/path/which/make/me/use/tab/for/..."))
    ((eq choice ?v)
     (find-file "/Users/HOME/.0.data/vocab.org")
     (message "Opened:  %s" (buffer-name)))
    ((eq choice ?g)
     (find-file "/Users/HOME/.0.data/gtd.org")
     (message "Opened:  %s" (buffer-name)))
    ((eq choice ?d)
     (find-file "/Users/HOME/.0.data/diary.org")
     (message "Opened:  %s" (buffer-name)))
    ((eq choice ?n)
     (find-file "/Users/HOME/.0.data/notes.org")
     (message "Opened:  %s" (buffer-name)))
    (t (message "Quit"))))
```

---

Pursuant to the request of the original poster in a comment underneath the initial answer, the following is an example of how to select window letter `A`:

```lisp
(defun example-fn-two ()
  "To try this example, type:  M-x example-fn"
  (interactive)
  (let ((window-a nil)
        (window-b (selected-window))
        (window-c nil)
        (buffer-a (dired-noselect "~"))
        (buffer-b (find-file-noselect "~/foo.txt"))
        (buffer-c (get-buffer-create "*scratch*")))
    (delete-other-windows)
    (set-window-buffer window-b buffer-b)
    (setq window-a
          (window--display-buffer
           buffer-a (split-window window-b nil 'left)
           'window '((window-width . 70)) display-buffer-mark-dedicated))
    (setq window-c
          (window--display-buffer
           buffer-c (split-window window-b nil 'below)
           'window nil display-buffer-mark-dedicated))
    (select-window window-a)))
```

Comment: This works still perfectly but I am trying to modify a little detail: the focus is on the last buffer opened (c). How can I put it on buffer a?

Comment: `window--display-buffer` returns the WINDOW.  You can wrap the last statement that deals with `c` using `(select-window (window--display-buffer c ....))` and that will select window `c`.  The code assumes we wanted `b` selected, so you might want to use `set-window-buffer` with the appropriate arguments instead of `switch-to-buffer`, but you don't have to change that portion if you don't want to.

Comment: Sorry I was incorrect. The focus is indeed on the buffer `b`. I would like to have it on buffer `a`. I tried to change the last part of the code for `(select-window (window--display-buffer a (window--display-buffer c (split-window (selected-window) nil 'below)
       'window nil display-buffer-mark-dedicated)))))`. But I have still the focus on `b`.

Comment: I have labeled the buffers and windows more distinctively in the new `example-fn-two`.  When we split left and when we spit below, we need to visualize in our own mind that we are in window `B`.  The last line can be changed to suit your needs -- i.e., you can just change the window letter of the last line to any of the three possibilities; or, if you want to select `B` you could even omit the last line since we were initially in window `B` to begin with.

Comment: I tried to adapt this example to open only to files (on the left and the other on the right). I deleted everything related to buffer/window c but I have an error messsage "let: Symbol’s value as variable is void: buffer-b".

Comment: Here is what I tried: https://paste.aperture-sc.net/?f637ad52697b916f#/q7p+Vwr68k6weX4Aip3LA0A5pSo3IxF5koQcbQdmtk=