# Setting up an maintaining my window layout

Tags: window, display-buffer-alist

I'd like to have my Emacs frame setup with a neotree window on the left, my active source code or text file taking up the majority of window's space.
I'd like to have Emacs put virtually all other windows at the bottom of the window space (*messages* buffer, REPL's, compilation logs, etc)

I've been researching display-buffer-alist and so forth but I'm new to customizing Emacs so my grasp of terminology my incomplete.

Is there some combination of display-buffer-alist settings or some elisp that can maintain this setup as I work?

Comment: In a nutshell, setting a window to be dedicated is your friend:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html  In terms of targeting and/or creating windows in a certain direction, there are too many possibilities to answer the question in detail and it will be necessary to look at the individual functions responsible.  You can also control whether it is a vertical or horizontal split to some extent with `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold`: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html

Comment: Here is a link to an example called `example-fn` that I wrote up a couple of weeks ago describing how to achieve a specific layout with three (3) windows, and how to control the window width at the time of creation:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26970/2287  As you continue to use Emacs, you find behavior you want to change and each change will require an investment of time finding out the source of the behavior and how to modify it to suit your needs.