# How to open two files in two frames on startup?

Tags: init-file, window-splitting, find-file

Here's what I'm trying to make happen: on startup, I want emacs to split vertically into two windows displaying two different files, with my to-do list on the left side of the screen and my notes on the right.

I've already set things up to automatically split the screen into two buffers by adding `(split-window-right)` to my init file. I've also set it to automatically load the two files I want, using `(find-file...)`. But I can't figure out how to assign a different file to each window at startup. Instead, it's just loading the same buffer in both windows.

Any help?

Comment: Check out the examples in my answer to a similar question and see if one of them suits your needs:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26967/open-several-files-in-a-specifc-layout-with-a-shortcut  The third optional argument to `split-window` is the direction:  `'left`, `'right`, `'below`, and  `'above`.