# Split Emacs Screen Three Ways

Tags: window-splitting

In my .emacs file I have `(split-window-right)`. This has been working fine so far, but now I'm finding it would be easier if my workspace looked like: [image: a square split into quads, with the two left quads joined to a column]

where each box is a separate window. So really I just need to split the right window in half after the initial split on startup. How can I do this?

Comment: Here is a link to an answer containing some examples of how to create custom split window setups:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26970/2287

Answer (score 9):

you can:

- add  this to your `.emacs` file

```lisp
(split-window-right)
(other-window 1)
(split-window-below)
(other-window -1)
```

- set it up manually any time: `C-x 3` `C-x o` `C-x 2` `C-- C-x o`
- consider using one of those window manager extensions, like [edwina](https://github.com/ajgrf/edwina), if your requeriments become more complex.

Any option you choose taking a look to `C-h i m emacs [RET] m windows` will be useful.

Comment: Hello, when I add this to my codes it gives me an error saying "Wrong number of arguments". I see the second other-window took an argument. Does the first other-window need an argument?

Comment: yes, a positive 1. My fault, sorry. Already corrected.

Comment: Hmmm... when I did that now I get this error: Window #<window 7 on *scratch*> too small for splitting. The big vertical split happens, but the smaller horizontal split doesn't go through. Also, when I open a file, it opens the file on the right instead of the left. Any ideas?

Comment: it should be a very small window, or you have a couple of windows in that frame which seems the case given the window number. For simplicity I've put only the simplest code needed to make the desired split and assumed that there is only a window. You could add `(delete-other-windows)` as first line. As it is, if it fails to complete the third command, whatever you make will happen in the active window.